# Is there anyway to make the URL of an object in my AWS S3 bucket inaccessible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, private, cdn

I have some images on my website that are loaded in via S3 however I want to make those URL's private/inaccessible without compromising the visibility of the image on my site.. Is this possible?

When I make the URL of the object private like so:
[image]

It addresses me with the following page upon attempting to view it:

I am fairly new at S3.. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: You need to dynamically generate [Pre-Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for your clients, so that only the clients with the urls can access the S3 Objects.
If you're going to use the Objects as assets then consider Amazon CloudFront as CDN, for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If the S3 URL is embedded in your page, then the client has to be able to read the file from S3, which means it needs to be public.  S3 is no different from any other web resource in that way.

Comment: What about... If the web site content is dynamic, the object can be private and the site can generate and embed pre-signed URLs. Or if the bucket is placed behind CloudFront, the objects can be made visible only if the browser is in possession of a pre-signed cookie.  Or, S3 can natively allow/deny based on `Referer`.  That last one is not secure but prevents hotlinking.

Comment: Or you could run a reverse proxy in EC2 and require the links or... There are a hundred ways to do it with additional programming or more complex infrastructure, but none of those are turnkey and require treating the question as one that is too broad for SO.

Comment: Agreed, there are many ways to do it.... which was the intention behind the comment -- I intended it as a suggestion, not that you should suggest "the solution" (since we don't really have enough information and as you correctly point out, it is a very broad area with many options), but rather that your answer might mention that S3 does have mechanisms allowing the securing of content (though it's not as simple as checking a checkbox) and these depend to varying extents on the current site's implementation/environment, the level of security needed, and the motivation for restricting access.